# Shutdown Order of Windows Services

Tags: windows, service

Let there be three types of services as follows:

1. Services that accept pre-shutdown notifications and are ordered in the "PreshutdownOrder" registry setting. (Type A)
2. Services that accept pre-shutdown notifications and are unordered, that is, they are not listed in the "PreshutdownOrder" registry setting. (Type B)
3. Services that do not accept pre-shutdown notifications. (Type C)

According to the [Shutdown Ordering](https://books.google.com/books?id=Q5xCAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT1195&lpg=PT1195&dq=delay+shutdown+of+windows+services+based+on+preshutdown+notifications&source=bl&ots=Hu0_pLinmq&sig=PEh4BRg0YJ8mF5x9QkmATI20bBI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwibgrOM3-7LAhXBTSYKHZ8uC64Q6AEIOjAF#v=onepage&q=delay%20shutdown%20of%20windows%20services%20based%20on%20preshutdown%20notifications&f=false) link, it seems that services of type A shutdown before services of type B.

Based on my testing with a service (say SA) that does not accept pre-shutdown notification (a type C service) and a service (say SB) that does accept pre-shutdown notification (can be of type A if listed in the registry or type B if not listed in the registry), I observed that SB always shutdown before SA irrespective of whether both SA and SB were listed in the "PreshutdownOrder" registry setting in any order or not.

So while I observed that type C service shuts down after type A and B services, however, I am unable to find documentation for the same. Can someone point me to relevant documentation that would confirm this behavior to always be true?

I am asking this question because I am using third-party whitelisting service SA and would like it to always shut down after service SB that is developed in-house.

Comment: SA doesn't understand pre-shutdown notifications, SB does, so of course SB will shut down first regardless of shutdown order, since SA won't do anything when it is sent the pre-shutdown request.  By definition the "pre-shutdown" will occur first, so unless a type A or type B service hangs, it will shut down before type C.  Your Shutdown Ordering link documents the behavior of this, since services that do not understand pre-shutdown notifications will not receive the pre-shutdown request when the computer begins to shutdown.  What do you want documentation to explain further?

Comment: Thanks Matt for taking time to go through my post and respond. From what I understood, Shutdown Ordering link mentions the following: Services that register for pre-shutdown notifications and are ordered in the registry shutdown before services that register for pre-shutdown notifications and are not ordered in the registry. Where does it mention that services that register for pre-shutdown notifications shutdown before services that do not register for pre-shutdown notifications? Is it something you are deducing from what is mentioned in the link?

Comment: In my testing I made SB register for pre-shutdown notifications and delayed its shutdown by two minutes. Service SA is a third-party service, I do not have access to its source and based on results of `sc query` command, this service does not register for pre-shutdown notifications. Still service SB shutdown before service SA. Although I want this behavior but I do not have proof that this behavior would always hold true. Hence I am looking for related documentation on the topic.

Comment: You want behavior that is not true at least some of the time, is that correct?  If that statement is correct, you cannot rely on that behavior at all.  So, unless you need to prove that you cannot accomplish the goal, your real goal is to find a way to provide this shutdown order - have you looked into setting the 3rd party whitelisting service as a dependency of your in-house service, so Windows knows that the in-house service must stop before its dependency, and start after?

Comment: Thanks again Matt. After reading "When the user shuts down the system, all control handlers that have called SetServiceStatus with the SERVICE_ACCEPT_PRESHUTDOWN control code receive the SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN control code. The service control manager waits until the service stops or the specified preshutdown time-out value expires." in [Service Control Handler Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685149(v=vs.85).aspx), it seems that services registering for  pre-shutdown notifications shutdown before services that do not do so. Do you agree?